# Change image of UIImageView on button click in iPhone program

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I want to change image in image viewer when I click a button.
I know this question basic but, I need an answer for this.
Please reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, implement the following method in a MyViewController.m (also, add method signature to MyViewController.h file):

MyViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)handleButtonClick:(id)sender {
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blah.png"];
}
```

MyViewController.h:

```
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
}

- (IBAction)handleButtonClick:(id)sender;
```

Then attach handleButtonClick action to button's Touch up inside event and imageView outlet to your image view in Interface builder.

Voila.